# Загрузка изображений Joomla

Tags: php, html, joomla

Необходимо выполнить загрузку с помощью Ajax изображения, но проблема в том, что даже если я не вывожу в функции модуля ничего, но возвращается копия страницы.

Код js:

```
function uploadServer($el) {
var fileUpload = $el.get(0);
var file = fileUpload.files[0];
var url;
if (file) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('image', file);

    var request = {
        'option': 'com_ajax',
        'module': 'constructor',
        'method': 'uplodeImage',
        'val'   :  data,
        'format': 'raw',
    };
    console.log(request);
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        data: request,
        success: function (response) {
            url = response;
        }
    }).done(function(response){
        url = response;
    });
}
$('#debug').html(url);
return url;
```

модуль joomla:

```
class modConstructorHelper
{

    // Загрузка изображений во временную папку 
    public static function uplodeImage() {

        jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
        jimport('joomla.application.input.files');

    }

}
```

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что в $('#debug').html(url); переменная url будет ?, попробуйте поставить $('#debug').html(url); именно в    success: function (response) { }

Comment: Это же синхронный запрос и заметил, если убрать `contentType:false, processData:false,` то все хорошо, но не передаются файлы

Comment: А вам нужны параметры contentType и processData ? или просто так поставили ?

Comment: А без них ошибка в консоли `TypeError: 'slice' called on an object that does not implement interface Blob.` И на сколько мне известно необходимо запретить преобразование передаваемых данных в строку с помощью `processData=false`, ну и отключить кодировку `contentType=false`